# work with dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox

I create tablerows and checkboxes dynamically with a code like this:

```
    for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Users p = (Users) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        /** Creating a Checkbox to add to the row **/
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(p.getEan());
        LinearLayout Ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        Ll1.addView(cb);
        System.out.println(j);
        tr.addView((View)Ll1); // Adding CheckBox to tablerow.  

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getName());
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

After its created the user can check or uncheck.
With the check, I need to do run another command for every checkbox.

My problem is, how do I use the checkboxes? How i can "speak" with so i can work with it?

Comment: when you want to `run another command for every checkbox.` ??

Comment: @hevilp Post the source in your onCheckedChangeListener method.

Comment: the other command must be based upon the text of the checkbox?

Comment: @ Salmann, right that, in the text of the checkbox is an ean-code. if the checkbox is checked, a php-mysql-value will be set. i will post my whole code later, when i am arrived @home

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K , i am thinking about which is the best way. in the moment of check/uncheck for every checkbox (for every box a php-call) or a seperate command for example a button click for a while-loop.(all checkboxes are checked step by step for check/uncheck and one array for the php-call)

Answer (score 0):

Call [generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) (or leave `setId(i)`) and use generated id in [setId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) for your programatically generated checkboxes. Save id's locally during your activity life and use this id's in same way as static id's from R. in setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: this seems to be the method to loop all generated id's and check it. can u give me a code example pls?

Answer (score 0):

You gave the rows and checkboxes the same id's. Don't give the rows id's. Or different ones.

You can place following code in on check change listeners.

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < Array_Count; i++) 
{
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)my_layout.findViewById(i);

if ( checkBox == null )
    continue;

Toast.makeText(context, checkBox.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

checkBox.setText("my id is: " + i);
}
```

Comment: thank you for this,but: what is array_count? it belongs to the ArrayList "Users". the code ist not useable for me now.

Comment: That for loop with Array_Count came from your posted code.  You have removed that code obviously. You can use that code if you get the idea of it.

Comment: and why i need to set layout? even the line LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_einbuchen); doesnt work

Comment: i changed to code my real code in another post, so dont post here, its not usefull, i am sorry.